# Changing variables using user input

Tags: java, variables

I have to write a code for class.  These are the requirements:

One class should be the Controller with the main method.

The other class should:

- do some action
- pass in variables
- use at least one if statement
- have private methods
- have some getters and setters.

I have done most of this.  I ran into a problem where I want the user to type 'Go Forward' and then for the stamina to be decreased by five and have a message appear in the sonsole saying, "You lose 5 stamina."  And also I'd like for the user to be able to type 'Rest' and for the stamina to increase by 5 (capping at 100, and for the console to say, "Stamina increased to #."

I don't know how to increase/decrease the stamina though.  Whenever I try something, I get an error.

If there'es something I have that I don't need, then tell me what it is and why I should remove it.  If there is something that's public and doesn't need to be, tell me why it shouldn't be.  My teacher says that later on, there will be a 5 point deduction for every time something is public that doesn't need to be.

Here's the code:

Controller Class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Controller {
  public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("Type your name here:");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scan.nextLine();         
    Player playerOne = new Player(input);
          playerOne.setStrength(78);
          playerOne.setHealth(99);
          playerOne.setStamina(67);
          playerOne.printplayer();

          System.out.println("Type 'Go Forward' to move forward");
          Scanner mscan = new Scanner(System.in);
          //mscan = movement scan   
          String minput = scan.nextLine();
                if(minput.equals("Go Forward"))
                    //minput = movement input
                    System.out.println("You lose 5 stamina.");
                    //Getting an error here : 'stamina cannot be resolved to a variable'
                    System.out.println("Stamina: " + stamina);
                if(minput.equals("Rest"))   
                //Getting an error here : 'stamina cannot be resolved to a variable'
                    System.out.prinln("Stamina has been increased to " + stamina);
                     scan.close(); 
                     }
}
```

And the Player Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player{

        public String name; 
        private String input;
        private double health;


        public double strength;

        public double stamina;

        //Player Name
         public Player (String input){
          name = input;
       }

       //Player Health
         public void setHealth(double playHp){
             health = playHp;
       }
       //Player Strength
       public void setStrength(double playStrn){
          strength = playStrn;
       }
       //Player Stamina
       public void setStamina(double playStam){
          stamina = playStam;
       }

       public void printplayer(){
          System.out.println("name  : " + name );
          System.out.println("Health :" + health);
          System.out.println("Strength :" + strength);
          System.out.println("Stamina :" + stamina);

            }

       private void reduceStamina() {
           int stamina;

         }
    public int getStamina() {

        return 0;
    }
}

          System.out.println("Type 'Go Forward' to move forward");
          Scanner mscan = new Scanner(System.in);
          //mscan = movement scan   
          String minput = scan.nextLine();
                if(minput.equals("Go Forward"))
                    //minput = movement input
                    System.out.println("You lose 5 stamina.");
                    //Getting an error here : 'stamina cannot be resolved to a variable'
                    System.out.println("Stamina: " + stamina);
                if(minput.equals("Rest"))   
                //Getting an error here : 'stamina cannot be resolved to a variable'
                    System.out.prinln("Stamina has been increased to " + stamina);
                     scan.close(); 
                     }
}
```

Comment: `"I don't know how to increase/decrease the stamina though. Whenever I try something, I get an error."` -- Please show what you've tried and the full error messages that this causes. Else we won't know what you might be doing wrong, or what incorrect assumptions you might be making.

Comment: `stamina` is a field of `Player`, you should provide a `getStamina` method in your `Player` class and use `playerOne.getStamina()` when you want to display it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer you're right, but he set stamina to public so that doesn't look like the overall problem. It's wrong, but it won't generate an error like he is getting.

Comment: @lacraig2 *"//Getting an error here : 'stamina cannot be resolved to a variable'"*, the OP is not referencing the `Player` instance at all, they've just used a undefined variable in the `main` method called `stamina` ... and don't get me started on `public` fields

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't like it either, but his problem is that he's not calling playerOne.stamina (or getStamina() if he set up the method correctly, not that he isn't properly protecting his data.

Comment: @lacraig2 That's what I said...

Comment: @MadProgrammer. You had the solution before I did (I didn't see the error in the comment), however, I'm still glad I commented because I even though you had the correct answer it wasn't clear from your first comment what he should do to fix his code (he doesn't even seem to understand getters and setters).

Comment: @lacraig2 Clear as mud :)

Answer (score 1):

To use a variable in Java, you have to declare it first.
Example you would like to use an integer, you have to declare it

```
int mynumber = 1; //declare variable named mynumber and give it value is 1
```

You missed on how to declare a variable, that make 2 mistake I see in your code
 1. Reusable: you already declared a Scanner before, so you can use it again, dont have to declare one more Scanner named mscan
 2. Declare a variable: as I said before, if you want to use a variable, you have to declare it first. In your whole code, you did not declare stamina variable so you can not use it. That's the reason why you got error

> stamina cannot be resolved to a variable.

If you want to decrease stamina of that player, you should get current stamina, decrease it and set it back
For example:

```
double currentStamina = player.getStamina();
currentStamina = currentStamina - 5; // (or currentStamina-=5) decrease current stamina by 5
player.setStamina(currentStamina); // set current stamina for player
```

Next I will continue about your code.
The property of an object should not be declared as public (your fields 'name', 'strength', 'stamina'). They should be private and you can get/set value of them through the get/set methods.
You use stamina as variable but it is not referenced (I said you did not declare it before). Did you mean the stamina field of class Player?
So if you want to use a field of another object, you have to use like this:
instead of

```
System.out.println("Current stamina is " + stamina);
```

change it to

```
System.out.println("Current stamina is " + player.stamina);
```

But dont call like that, you should call:

```
System.out.println("Current stamina is " + player.getStamina()); // don't directly access field of an object, please call get/set instead
```

Next: IF and ELSE IF
You for get open and close brankets in your code for the `if` statements. If you dont have open and close brankets after your statement, it will only execute only 1 next line as the action for the previous condition.
And you should learn to use `else` keyword.

After the whole things, your code should be:

```
String minput = scan.nextLine();
double currentStamina = player.getStamina();
if(minput.equals("Go Forward"))
{
     currentStamina -= 5;
     System.out.println("You lose 5 stamina.");
     System.out.println("Stamina: " + currentStamina);
}
else if(minput.equals("Rest"))   
{
     currentStamina += 5;
     System.out.prinln("Stamina has been increased to " + currentStamina );
}
player.setStamina(currentStamina); // update stamina value to player
scan.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a public methods called getStamina,increaseStamina and decreaseStamina:

```
public int getStamina(){
   return stamina;
}

public void increaseStamina(int st){
   stamina+=st;
}

public void decreaseStamina(int st){
   stamina-=st;
}
```

Then in your program do something like:

```
Player player=new Player();
if(minput.equals("Go Forward"))
    System.out.println("You lose 5 stamina.")
    player.decreaseStamina(5);
    System.out.println("Stamina: " + player.getStamina());
```

Comment: He is a new to coding, your answer let him be a copy&paste robot.

Comment: My teacher teached as robot, I have some robot friend. So sad.